# Purpose and usage of "application.path" variable

Tags: java, playframework, getproperty

In the Play! framework source for the `main` method in `Server.java` I found these two lines:

```
File root = new File(System.getProperty("application.path"));
if (System.getProperty("precompiled", "false").equals("true")) {
    Play.usePrecompiled = true;
}
```

Where can I find the `application.path` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.getProperty("application.path")` that looks like a `-D` property. So at the start of the server there is a call like
`java -Dapplication.path=/opt/play/myApp`

`/play/framework/pym/play/application.py` in line 251 makes the work.

Answer (score 0):

It may be in your `application.conf` file. Check there.

Comment: no, application.conf file does not contain application.path line.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a properties file in your application and also there might be a mechanism to load all those properties into System properties.

Search for application.path in your application folder file contents and you may get a clue.